# !imporant equivalent for HTML class tag?

Tags: html, css, class, tags

I'm dealing with a real hash of a site, so this is why I'm asking about this absurd question.

I've looked everywhere to find some sort of way to make a class override another class in the HTML class tag to no avail.

I can either do this, try to untie a ton of spaghetti (which I probably won't be allowed to do anyways), or something anyone else can recommend (would be greatly appreciated).

Is this possible?

```
class="myClass !important"
```

If not, is there some sort of equivalent?

Please help!  Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Nope, not possible as far as I know.

Comment: And by the way, CSS class definitions are neither HTML nor tags.

Comment: `!important` is for propertie/value pairs alone; you'd use that inside your rules for that particular class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the ability to change the HTML templates, you can always go in and add a `<div id="override">` or something like that to the outer most wrapper of the page to use as the "master" rule in your CSS classes. Then, in the CSS, you can just add that ID before any of the existing classes or ones that you need to modify.

For instance, if you have the following and want to override the .some-class:

```
<div class="some-class">Bleh.</div>
```

And the corresponding CSS:

```
.some-class { color: red; }
```

You can wrap the whole thing with:

```
<div id="override">
    <div class="some-class">Bleh.</div>
</div>
```

And add the #override (or whatever you want to name it) before the .some-class and this rule will take precedence over the other:

```
#override .some-class { color: green; } /* This will override the red color form the other rule */
.some-class { color: red; }
```

Comment: That's much more like what I'm able to do under present circumstances.  Thank-you!  Will test n vote & check when I can.

Answer (score 3):

No, that's not possible. You're going to have to iron out the [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Specificity) by yourself I'm afraid.

Comment: This, largely, though it can be good to keep in mind that the last class listed in an HTML element will be the one that overrides the rest when the specificity is equal (ie - if you have element with `class="foo bar baz"` and CSS `.foo{} .bar{} .baz{}`, the styles for `.bar` will win conflicts with `.foo` and `.baz` will win any conflicts it has with either of them). This tidbit may save some headache, depending on how convoluted the CSS is.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `!important` for entire selectors. You need to find the specific rules you want to override, and use `!important` on each.

Answer (score 0):

You can add more than one class to a selector as follows:

```
class="myClass myClass2"
```

Above is what the class attribute would look like on your HTML element.

As far as the CSS goes, define the classes as follows:

```
.myClass {
    color: black;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

The above is just a sample of some properties you may have.

Defining "myClass2" after "myClass" in your stylesheet will allow the properties from "myClass2" to overrided the matching ones in "myClass":

```
//This goes below myClass
.myClass2 {
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

As long as "myClass2" is after "myClass", your font will take the size property of '16px;' The value of "myClass" will be overwritten by that of "myClass2". If "myClass2" comes before "myClass", you can use !important to ensure that style is taken over the one defined later:

```
//This goes above myClass
.myClass2 {
    font-size: 16px !important;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

CSS classes are just a group of styles so you can use `class` instead of inline `style` tag.
The `!important` keyword helps you to override a specific style and not working on classes.
So, for example:

Lets say that we have a css rule on every `div` somewhere in our CSS file

```
div{border:solid 1px #ff0000;}
```

And later on we have this rule:

```
div{background:#000000;}
```

Every `div` in our page will be with `border` and a `background` if we want to override the `div` css rules we need to do something like this:

```
div{background:none !important;border:none !important;/*...ADD YOUR CSS...*/}
```

you can create a css reset class to reset all the settings that you want and than add your css